# How can make array of string

Tags: php

```
$var = {"4":true,"6":true,"8":true}
```

In The above string I want to get numbers into array.

```
Need: $var2 = [[0]=>4, [1]=>6, [2]=>8];
```

All response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to accomplish it:

```
array_keys(json_decode($var, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

As i comment, use `array_keys`, and `json_decode`.

> I don't believe that this question has an answer, So i did't answer
>   it. But i did it later.

You have an json, so you need to use `json_decode` now you jave an array where your keys are the desired value. so use array_keys.

```
$var = '{"4":true,"6":true,"8":true}';
$arr = json_decode($var, true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_keys($arr));
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you decode the string using `json_decode`, the second argument means that the function should return an associative array and non an array of  objects. This willl help up get the array keys.

```
$decoded = json_decode($var, true);
```

You get the array keys with this loop and place them in `$var`

```
foreach($decoded as $key => $value){
   $var2[] = $key;
}
```